# PHP timestamp/membership system not expiring on the exact date

Tags: php, system, membership

I'm having a few problems while creating a small membership system with timestamps. When I show the timestamp in a date, it will tell me when the active membership expires. However, on that time/date, it will NOT expire, and the script that resets membership, and counts from -NUMBERHERE.

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong? I'm doing `(time() - $timestamp)` to work it out. Here's my script(s);

```
$membership = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `membership` > 0 AND `membertype` > 0") or die(mysql_error());
while($mm = mysql_fetch_array($membership)){

  if((time() - $mm["membership"]) > $mm["membertype"]){
     mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `membership` = 0, `membertype` = 0 WHERE `username` = '" . $mm[username] . "'");
  } else {
     echo (time() - $mm["membership"]);
  }

}  

$membership_date  = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $user["membership"]);
echo "Your membership expiry date: $membership_date";
```

It does expire, but it expires very late. Any help will be great, thanks.

P/S: the `membertype` variable is the amount of seconds until it expires.

Comment: What fails when exactly? Can you make an example?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XsJrsKv0

When I refresh the file for it to update on the exact timestamp it needs to expire, it won't because it's also counting from -NUMBEROFSECONDS

Comment: I'm not sure this can be diagnosed without knowing that `$mm['membership']` actually contains. However, I would venture that the problem should be examined at the point where that variable is initially set.

Comment: Time zone issue? If PHP and MySQL's TZ settings differ, then your timestamps will be off by some multiple of 3600 seconds.

Comment: Marc, PHP created the timestamp and inserted it into MySQL? So I don't know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a user:

```
$membership = time() + $membertype;
```

Then set up your query and execute.

When retrieving a user:

Replace this line

```
if((time() - $mm["membership"]) > $mm["membertype"]){
```

with this:

```
if( time() >= $user["membership"] )
```

Comment: I never thought of that, haha. My brain obviously thinks differently from everyone else's. Thank you, Andy.